# Using a variable with a dollar sign in it in bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, sed

I have a variable that contains a string with $ dollar signs in it and I want to use `sed` to modify a text file. I get an error whenever there is a dollar sign in the variable but it works fine when there's no dollar sign. How can I fix this? I am using multiple variables and literal text in one double quote.

The code:

```
sudo sed -i "textFile.txt" -e "s,\($var1\):\(.*:\):,\1:$var2WithDollarSign:$var3,g" textfile.txt
```

Comment: Show us the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is the dollar signs causing trouble?  Does it contain any commas too?  You could help us to help you by including sample values for `$var1`, `$var2WithDollarSign` and `$var3`, and also by including the exact error message you get from ... is it `sed` or the shell that complains?  We'd know if you'd provided the exact error message.

Comment: there are no commas but there are /'s

Comment: The variable is random data (copying an encrypted string), the error is sed: -e expression #1, char 122: undetermined `s' command

Comment: I essentially need to copy the var2, modify the var1 and var3 and then write it back with the modified var1 and var3 while keeping var2 intact including the dollar signs and \'s

Comment: I see no problem with this command: `var1=VAR1 var2WithDollarSign='VAR2$W' var3=VAR3 sed -e "s,\($var1\):\(.*:\):,\1:$var2WithDollarSign:$var3,g" <<< 'hello VAR1:blabla::world'`. You have provide more information.

Comment: what I am saving in the variable is the second field from a user account in the /etc/shadow file ad when that is used in sed it gives errors. when it is echo'd it displays blank lines with *'s on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're running `sudo` to run the `sed` command:

```
sudo sed -i "textFile.txt" -e "s,\($var1\):\(.*:\):,\1:$var2WithDollarSign:$var3,g" textfile.txt
```

The trouble is that the shell you're using process the arguments once, then the shell that `sudo` runs on your behalf processes the arguments a second time.  I recommend creating a shell script that contains the `sed` command and sets the shell variables, and then run that from `sudo`.

```
cat > script <<!
sed -i "textFile.txt" -e 's,\($var1\):\(.*:\):,\1:$var2WithDollarSign:$var3,g' textfile.txt
!
sudo sh -x script
rm -f script
```

It will save a lot of brain-power.

#### Example

```
$ cat xx.sh
var1='theperson'
var2WithDollarSign='the$voodoo$wizard'
var3='Albuquerque'
cat > script <<!
sed -i "textFile.txt" -e 's,\($var1\):\(.*:\):,\1:$var2WithDollarSign:$var3,g' textfile.txt
!
cat script
rm -f script
$ sh xx.sh
sed -i "textFile.txt" -e 's,\(theperson\):\(.*:\):,\1:the$voodoo$wizard:Albuquerque,g' textfile.txt
$
```

I've replaced `su sh -x script` with `cat script`.  You'd undo that substitution.  The `-x` is optional; it just shows you what the script is executing.

Comment: That seems great but I don't understand it and probably cannot adapt it to work correctly... I'm on week 4 on a uni course on Linux with 0 experience before hand sorry, they're really throwing us in the deep end, so to speak

Comment: @StevenCragg: Why are you running scripts as the [super user](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) then, anyway?

Comment: I need sudo to access the text file in this question and do not have su to use nor the root account

Comment: In a sys. Admin. course at uni Working on scripts to user data in the passwd and shadow files and say we can use sudo but not root account nor su. I fail to see the difference between su and sudo but I'm sure I will later in the course.

Comment: Don't do anything as root until you know that it will work precisely and correctly.  It's too damn dangerous.  Experimenting with scripts using root privileges is a bad idea.

Comment: One major difference between `su` and `sudo` is that `su` requires the root password to get root privileges, but `sudo` requires your password (instead of root's password) to get root privileges. The other major difference is that `su` is all-or-nothing but `sudo` allows the admins to control what sudoers can do.

Comment: we're using virtualbox and have a backup of the install for that reason.

Comment: I'm also working with copies of the file until it works 100%, which it does besides this bit, but works when there's no dollar signs in the variable

Comment: and modifying the "games" user of which i have no idea what it's for and never logged into it. it's a clean install of Ubuntu with only a few changes as we're learning them

Comment: alternatively I'd liek to leave the var2 where it is and re-write the stuff around it but i failed to do this as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to backslash the special characters. It might be easier to switch to a more powerful tool, e.g. Perl, which already has functions to do that (`quotemeta`, `s/\Q$var\E/.../`).

Comment: I am new to Bash and haven't even thought about Perl yet. I'm essentially getting help on a uni assignment question

Comment: @StevenCragg: Then just prepend \ before each character that has a special meaning in sed. For example: `x='Price $20'; x=${x//$/\\$}`.

Comment: will this work for a variable that might be jhg78g$buih789$.khbyi7vuy/nij and has no set amount of dollar signs?

Comment: @Steven: TITS or Try It To See :-) Note that `.` is also special in regexp patterns.

Comment: so i should do the above twice? once for $ and once for .?